# Staggering a list of posts into two columns in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a list of posts ordered by most recent date of modification. I want to stagger them into two columns to have the two recent modified posts at the top. This code is fairly self explanatory:

```
posts.each do |post|
  right_column << post if shift
  left_column << post if !shift
  shift = shift ? false : true
end

posts = left_column + right_column
```

For example, given the input  `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the goal is to produce `[1, 3, 2, 4]`.

Is there a more elegant/idiomatic way to achieve this in Ruby?

Comment: rather you could give some examples..input and expected output..

Comment: @Babai added a simple example.

Comment: that imperative style is terribly unidiomatic, search for ruby+functional+programming.

Comment: @tokland That's exactly why I am asking for a more idiomatic way to do it...

Comment: @louism: Of course! My point was that a particular solution fot this problem won't help much, you need to be aware of the functional principles as a whole. Hope that helps: https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to get the rows, then [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) it into columns, then [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) them:

```
posts = (1..10).to_a  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

posts.each_slice(2).to_a.transpose.flatten
#=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Or, to get the left and right columns separately:

```
left, right = posts.each_slice(2).to_a.transpose
```

Comment: Why stop there when `posts = posts.each_slice(2).to_a.transpose.flatten` does the whole job?

Comment: @Borodin Because when I answered the question there was no sample input/output `:)`. Updated now, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I have noticed that you need `left_column` and  `right_column` only as temporary variables.

You may prefer this

```
posts = %W{ A B C D E F G H I J}

indices = posts.each_index.partition(&:even?).flatten
posts = posts.values_at(*indices)

p posts
```

**output**

```
["A", "C", "E", "G", "I", "B", "D", "F", "H", "J"]
```

---

If you use `each_with_index` you can push to different arrays depending on whether the index is even or odd

```
posts.each_with_index do |post, i|
  (i.even? ? left_column : right_column) << post
end
```

Comment: Using `each_index` & `partition` is creative, +1.

Comment: @tokland: Just swap `partition` for `group_by{|i| i % 3}.values`